# How to Get row values as columns in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have a table Test with two columns.

```
Id  Value
1    A
1    B
1    C
```

I want to get the result like below,

```
Id   Value1  Value2  value3
1      A       B       C
```

How can I done this in SQL Server.

Comment: this has been answered thousands of times on SO. please look at such questions before posting a new one.

Comment: You can literally take your post title, put it in google, and click the first link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pivot, but you don't have a column for the pivoting.  `row_number()` can provide that.  I usually use conditional aggregations for this.

```
select id,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then value end) as value1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then value end) as value2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then value end) as value3
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by id;
```

Note that SQL tables represent unordered sets.  So, there is no information about ordering and the values could be in any order.  If a column does specify the ordering, then include that in the `order by` rather than `select null`.